# React Native Tabnavigation Animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've implemented the tabnavigator with animation enabled with the following codes (ommitted icons codes for readability).

As you can see the navigation, as I click on each tab (e.g, first tab then 5th tab), the icons in the middle all changed color. Is there a way I can "jump" to the tab, while enabling animation?

```
const FirstStack = createTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    List: { screen: List },
    Check: { screen: Check },
    Open: { screen: Open },
    Settings: { screen: Settings }
  },
  {

    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#00af9d",
      inactiveTintColor: "grey",
      style: {
        backgroundColor: "white",
        paddingTop: 10
      },
      showLabel: false
    },
    animationEnabled: true
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the docs says for react-navigation, to enable animation in bottom tabs you need the material design tabs , you can learn about them and how to install them [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html)

Comment: you may want to see my question again. also included animated gif

Comment: You want what's in the gif? If so, then maybe you will need to create your own tab bar component to make it more customizable. Here it says [https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4146] that in RNav 2.0 the property animationenabled was removed in createBottomTabNavigator. So you will need to use tabBarComponent property and pass your own component with the navigation prop there, then just animate it.You can also do this in RNav 1.0